# Prove that the second derivative is positive iff the function is convex.

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, proof-writing

Well, I want to prove the following:

Let $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb R$ be double differentiable then $f$ is convex iff $\;\;f''(x)>0$ for all $x\in (a,b)$.

Then I tried te following:

$\Rightarrow]$ Lets suppose that $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb R$  is convex then if we define $h=-y+x$
we have that:

$$ f(x+h) \leq (1-t)f(x)+tf(x+h)$$

$$0 \leq (1-t)f(x)+tf(x+h)-f(x+h)$$

I was expecting to have something of this form

$$0 \leq f(x+h)-2f(x)+f(x-h)$$

and then take limit and have the result, I don't know how to define $h$ to have the above relation, Can someone help me ?

$\Leftarrow]$ I checked this, but I don't know if it is right, If it is not Can you help me to fix the mistakes please:

[Second derivative positive $\implies$ convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/513887/second-derivative-positive-implies-convex)

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 4):

From convexity, $f(ta+ (1-t)b) \leqslant tf(a) + (1-t)f(b)$.

Let $t = 1/2$, $a= x-h$, and $b = x+h$.

Then

$$f(x) \leqslant \frac1{2}f(x-h) + \frac1{2}f(x+h)\\ \implies f(x+h) - 2f(x) + f(x-h) \geqslant 0$$

Comment: Thanks a lot s a lovely proof, but can I fix t?

Comment: Convexity means the inequality holds for any $t \in [0,1]$

Comment: Right :) thanks a lot, what about the second part?

Comment: Is that proof right?

Comment: Are you also trying to show $f''(x) > 0 \implies $ convexity.  Use Taylors Theorem.

Comment: Yes, thats right but There is a discussion in the above link about it and I want to be sure that is right :)

Comment: @user162343: The proof in the linked question is correct. Multiply the first and second inequalities by $\lambda$ and $(1-\lambda)$, respectively, and add. The terms involving $f'$ cancel and you get the convextity condition.

Comment: Ok then with that proof the second part is covered right?

Comment: Yes, $f'' >0 \implies$ convexity

Comment: ok thanks a lot ;), only one thing I want to prove that $a^{1-t}>(1-t)a+tb$, then I should prove that $t \to a(b/a)^{t}$ is convex but how can I define the function to apply the criterion ?

Comment: What Im trying to ask is how can I define an $f$ for the relation $$t \to a(b/a)^{t}$$

Comment: @LucasMation: Please read this [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function).