# Is $\log(e^{x^a + x^b})$ a convex function?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Where $a$ and $b$ can be any real numbers, including fractional or negative. But $x$ is positive.

Comment: No. Take $a=b=-1$.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel what do you mean? $1/x$ is convex on $(0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\log(e^{x^a+x^b})$ simplifies to $x^a+x^b$, which is twice differentiable, so it's convex [iff its second derivative is nonnegative](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1175477/215011) over its domain (in your example the domain is $x>0$). This should lead to a counterexample. For simplicity try $a=b$.