# The sufficient condition for a function to be convex on the interval $[a;b]$

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

When I read about convex functions, I often encounter theorems of the following form: For a continuous function $f$ on the interval $[a;b]$ satisfying $f''(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in [a;b]$, then $f$ is a convex function on $[a;b]$.

I think it is possible to relax the sufficient condition at both endpoints while maintaining continuity. Specifically:

For a continuous function $f$ on the interval $[a;b]$ satisfying $f''(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in (a;b)$, prove that $f$ is a convex function on $[a;b]$.

I see that functions like $f(x)=-\sqrt{x}$ satisfy this condition. However, I don't yet know how to prove it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f:[a, b] \to \Bbb R$ is twice differentiable on the open interval $(a, b)$ with $f''(x) \ge 0$ then $f$ is convex on $(a, b)$. This can be proven with Taylor's theorem, see for example [Second derivative positive $\implies$ convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/513887/second-derivative-positive-implies-convex).

If $f$ is continuous on the closed interval $[a, b]$ and convex on $(a,b)$ then it is then $f$ is convex on $[a, b]$.

*Proof:* For $a < x < y < z < b$ is
$$
 \tag{$*$}
 f(y) \le \frac{z-y}{z-x} \cdot f(x) + \frac{y-x}{z-x} \cdot f(y) \, .
$$
Since $f$ is continuous, we can take the limit $x \to a$ and/or $z \to b$, so that $(*)$ holds for $a \le x < y < z \le b$.

*Remark:* It can be shown that if $f:[a, b] \to \Bbb R$ is convex on $(a, b)$ then both limits
$$
\lim_{x \to a} f(x) \, , \, \lim_{x \to b} f(x)
$$
exist in $\Bbb R\cup \{ + \infty \}$. $f$ is convex on $[a, b]$ if and only if
$$
\lim_{x \to a} f(x) \le f(a)\, , \, \lim_{x \to b} f(x) \le f(b) \, ,
$$
i.e. if $f$ is [upper semicontinuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-continuity) at $x=a$ and $x=b$.